# Number of homomorphisms from $(\mathbb Q^+ , \,\cdot\,)$ to $(\mathbb Z_n , +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

> How many homomorphism are there from $(\mathbb Q^+ , \,\cdot\,)$ to $(\mathbb Z_n , +)$?

Could anyone give a hint how to proceed?
I couldn't even start

Comment: what I only think, the only homomorphism between them is zero mapping, beside that, element $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ except identity have infinite order, but every element $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have finite order. Is it possible to mapping such element?

Comment: Please justify that there will be no other homomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely non-trivial homomorphisms from $\mathbb Q^+$  to $\mathbb Z_n$.

To see this, note that every positive rational number has a unique-upto-order "prime decomposition with negative powers". For example, $\frac{24}{35} = 2^{3}3^{1}5^{-1}7^{-1}$. Therefore, as is specified in a comment in the deleted answer above/below, $\mathbb Q^+$ under multiplication is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\displaystyle\oplus_{p \ \mathrm{ prime}} \mathbb Z$, via mapping each rational number, to the infinite tuple (with finitely many entries) of what power of each primes occurs in its decomposition.

Consequently, every such homomorphism is *uniquely* determined by what it does at the prime numbers. Here's why : let's write $p_1 < p_2 < p_3 < ...$ as the infinite sequence of prime numbers, and suppose you have a number $\frac{p}{q} = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} ...$ where $\alpha_i$ is a sequence of integers that becomes zero after some time, then by the homomorphism property : 
$$
\phi\left(\frac pq\right) = \phi\left(\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}\right) = \sum \alpha_i\phi(p_i) 
$$

where the sum is finite since $\alpha_i$ is eventually zero.

Consequently, to define a homomorphism, all you need to say is what it does at the prime numbers.

For example, let $\phi$ be the unique homomorphism such that $\phi(2) = \bar 1$ and $\phi(p) = \bar 0$ for all primes $p$ greater than $2$.

Then, for any rational $\frac pq$, $\phi\left(\frac pq\right)$ is equal to $\bar r$, where $\frac{p}{q} = 2^r3^s....$ You can check that this is a homomorphism.

---

You may ignore this if you do not know what countability means.

If you want the exact number of homomorphisms, then this is clear as well : each prime number (countably many prime numbers) is mapped to one of $n$ elements freely (where $n$ is finite).

Hence, one concludes that the number of homomorphisms is countable (countable number of finite choices amounts to countable choice), and definitely infinite, hence countably infinite.

---

On a side note, the deleted answer, which refers to the order of elements, makes sense for homomorphisms in the *opposite* direction i.e. from $\mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Q^+$. Indeed, if $\psi$ is a homomorphism, then let $\psi(1) = q$ for some $q$. Thus, $\psi(0) = \psi(1 + 1 + ... + 1) = \psi(1) \cdot ... \cdot \psi(1) = q^n$. Hence, $q^n = 1$ for some rational $q$ : this forces $q = 1$.

Hence, $\psi(l) = 1$ for every $l \in \mathbb Z_n$, hence $\psi$ is trivial.